# to fix the picture in the banner

Tags: html, css

![an aeroplane ][1]

```
#top
{
    background-color:maroon;
    width:100%;
    height:110px;
    background-image:url(im.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

I want the picture to fix in the banner. But I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Where is the image stored?  Try using a full path.

Comment: Please provide a Fiddle.

Comment: try setting `background-size:100% auto` and if you want to see the `background-color` then the `img` should be `transperent` a `png`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
       #sample{
    background-color:maroon;
    width:100%;
    height:110px;
    background-image:url(im.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 110px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='sample'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will only work if the image is at the same location as the web page.  If it's in a sub-directory, you will need to specify the path.

Comment: Yes. You will have to specify the full path.